# word end with dot, cant not be found through if loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
file = open('1.txt', 'w')

file.write("The ADJECTIVE panda walked to the NOUN and then VERB. A nearby NOUN was unaffected by these events.")

file.close()

change = open('1.txt')

openfile = change.read()

read = openfile.split()

keywords = ['ADJECTIVE', 'NOUN', 'ADVERB', 'VERB']

for i in read:

    if i in keywords:
        print(i)
        word = input('Please input %s:' % (i))
```

the word 'VERB' can not be found through this loop, anyone knows what is going wrong here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is caused by exact match while using `in` - So `VERB` is not equal to `VERB.`

While tokenizing you also have to remove punctuation - Without using modules like `nltk` etc. you could do it with simple `list comprehension`:

```
[''.join(c for c in word if c not in chrList) for word in sentence.split()]
```

##### Example

```
sentence = 'The ADJECTIVE panda walked to the NOUN and then VERB. A nearby NOUN was unaffected by these events.'
keywords = ['ADJECTIVE', 'NOUN', 'ADVERB', 'VERB']
chrList = ['.','!']

for word in [''.join(c for c in word if c not in chrList) for word in sentence.split()]:
    if word in keywords:
        print(word)
```

##### Output

```
ADJECTIVE
NOUN
VERB
NOUN
```